# kickstart partitioning error with LVM

Tags: redhat, lvm, kickstart

In Kickstart, I keep on getting the error;

> Adding this partition would not leave enough disk space for already
>   allocated logical volumes in vg_ibus

I do not get why I am getting this error. This device (ciss/c0d1) is 450G.  I simply want to make one Logical Volume inside that Volume Group.

These commands are from the Kickstart script that I am using;

```
part pv.d1 --size=1 --grow --ondisk=cciss/c0d1
volgroup vg_ibus pv.d1
logvol  /ibus  --vgname=vg_ibus  --size=450000  --name=lv_ibus
```

Answer (score 3):

It's likely not exactly 450G. Try to set a smaller size and use `--grow` so that the logical volume will grow to capacity of the block device. (Same as you are already doing for the physical partiion.)

`logvol /ibus --vgname=vg_ibus --size=1000 --name=lv_ibus --grow`

Comment: Thanks that appears to have been the problem, I originally decreased the partition by 20g but it appears that out of stated 450G I can only format 413U of it.

Comment: Glad that helped. Please don't forget to mark this answer as accepted. :)